# Handling multiple drop elements by class dynamically

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with figuring to make these drag and drop listeners into one function so dynamic zones can be created with the same class allowing me to call the same function for upload.  My upload function is working fine.  Just need to figure out how to make this function dynamically in one function.

```
<div id="dropZone1" class="dropZones" ></div>
<div id="dropZone2" class="dropZones" ></div>

     <script>

       var dropMedical = document.getElementById('dropZone1');
        dropMedical.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
        dropMedical.addEventListener('drop', fileSelect, false);

        var dropStatements = document.getElementById('dropZone2');
        dropStatements.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
        dropStatements.addEventListener('drop', fileSelect, false);

    </script>
```

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: this question appears to be lacking an actual question (or any question marks?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```js
dropZoneListener(zone) {
  zone.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
  zone.addEventListener('drop', fileSelect, false);
}

var dropMedical = document.getElementById('dropZone1');
dropZoneListener(dropMedical);

var dropStatements = document.getElementById('dropZone2');
dropZoneListener(dropStatements);
```

Comment: Thank you::::::    function dropZoneListener(zone) {
        zone.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
        zone.addEventListener('drop', fileSelect, false);
    }

    $('.dropZones').each(function (i, obj) {
        dropZone = $(this).attr('id');
        zoneInput = $(this).find("input").attr('id');
        var dropped = document.getElementById(dropZone);
        dropZoneListener(dropped);
    });